# Why does class exceed space in regards to the elements that it contains?

Tags: html, css

```css
:root {
  --clr-primary: #0F052F;
  --clr-secondary: #43D9B8;
  --clr-light: #EEEEEE;
  --fw-light: 300;
  --fw-regular: 400;
  --fw-medium: 500;
  --fw-bold: 700;
}

* {
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 1440px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0 100px;
}


/* Header - Navigation */

.desktop-nav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  width: 1240px;
  height: 100px;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 200;
  /* top: 44px; */
  padding-right: 0;
  background: white;
}

.desktop-nav .menu-items {
  display: flex;
  list-style: none;
}

.desktop-nav .menu-items li {
  margin: 0 27.5px;
}

.desktop-nav .menu-items li:nth-last-of-type(1) {
  margin-right: 0;
}

.desktop-nav .menu-items li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: var(--clr-primary);
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: var(--fw-medium);
  position: relative;
}

.desktop-nav .menu-items li a.active::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  height: 3px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: var(--clr-secondary);
  left: 0;
  bottom: -2px;
}

.desktop-nav .menu-items li a.btn {
  color: white;
  background-color: var(--clr-primary);
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 10px 23px;
}


/* BIA section */

.bia-container {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.bia-container .left h1 {
  font-size: 80px;
  font-weight: var(--fw-bold);
  margin: 84px 627px 18px 105px;
  color: white;
  line-height: 96px;
}

.bia-container .left p {
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: var(--fw-light);
  margin: 0px 632px 57px 105px;
  color: white;
}

.bia-container .left a.btn {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 10px 23px;
  border: 1px solid #43D9B8;
  margin: 0 0px 84px 105px;
  color: white;
}

.bia-container .right {
  padding-right: 105px;
}


/* Background header */

.bia-container .background {
  position: absolute;
  background: linear-gradient(135deg, #43D9B8 0%, #172443 64.58%, #0F052F 84.9%);
  border-radius: 50px 50px 300px 50px;
  width: 1240px;
  height: 585px;
  top: 112px;
}

.bia-container .background .right {
  position: absolute;
  top: 132px;
  right: 105px;
  left: 803px;
}


/* Animation */

.desktop-nav {
  animation: fadeDown 1000ms forwards;
  opacity: 0;
}

@keyframes fadeDown {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateY(-20px);
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
}

.bia-container .background .right {
  animation: fadeToLeft 800ms forwards cubic-bezier(0.22, 0.32, 0, 1.54);
  opacity: 0;
  animation-delay: 800ms;
}

@keyframes fadeToLeft {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateX(100px);
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <!-- Google Fonts-->
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@300;400;500;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <nav class="desktop-nav">
      <div class="logo">
        <a href="#">
          <img src="Images/bia-logo.svg" alt="">
      </div>

      <ul class="menu-items">
        <li>
          <a href="#" class="active">Home</a>
        </li>

        <li>
          <a href="#">Services</a>
        </li>

        <li>
          <a href="#">Contact</a>
        </li>

        <li>
          <a href="#" class="btn">Neem contact op</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>

    <!-- End of desktop navigation -->

    <header class="bia-container">
      <div class="background">
        <div class="left">
          <h1>Make data work for you</h1>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In ut neque faucibus gravida viverra tristique. Morbi quis commodo interdum id risus. Vitae hac viverra dui quis lobortis parturient purus. Libero pharetra tortor.</p>
          <a href="#" class="btn">Neem contact op</a>
        </div>

        <div class="right">
          <img src="Images/header-analytics.svg" alt="">
        </div>
      </div>
    </header>

    <!-- End of header section -->


  </div>

  <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Does anyone know why the class 'bia-container' is larger than just the header block? The elements within the class do not contain anything outside of the header block.

The problem I'm running into when trying to add content underneath the header block, is that the spacing is too large between the two 'blocks'.

In the image underneath you can see that the class 'bia-container' is larger than just the header block.

[image]

Comment: I don't understand your question very well but did you see the `height: 100vh`? It's basically a 100% (of the viewport height, not remaining space) height. So if your screen is 500px height, it will be 500px.

Answer (score 0):

It's because you're using `width: 100vh;` on your `bia-container`. Change it to `width: 100%;` and you should have no problem with large spaces when adding content underneath.

```css
:root {
  --clr-primary: #0F052F;
  --clr-secondary: #43D9B8;
  --clr-light: #EEEEEE;
  --fw-light: 300;
  --fw-regular: 400;
  --fw-medium: 500;
  --fw-bold: 700;
}

* {
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 100vw;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}


/* Header - Navigation */

.desktop-nav {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100px;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    /* top: 44px; */
    padding-right: 0;
    background: white;
}

.desktop-nav .menu-items {
  display: flex;
  list-style: none;
}

.desktop-nav .menu-items li {
  margin: 0 27.5px;
}

.desktop-nav .menu-items li:nth-last-of-type(1) {
  margin-right: 0;
}

.desktop-nav .menu-items li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: var(--clr-primary);
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: var(--fw-medium);
  position: relative;
}

.desktop-nav .menu-items li a.active::after {
  content: "";
  position: relative;
  height: 3px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: var(--clr-secondary);
  left: 0;
  bottom: -2px;
}

.desktop-nav .menu-items li a.btn {
  color: white;
  background-color: var(--clr-primary);
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 10px 23px;
}


/* BIA section */

.bia-container {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  position: relative;
}

.bia-container .left h1 {
  font-size: 80px;
  font-weight: var(--fw-bold);
  padding: 100px;
  color: white;
  line-height: 96px;
}

.bia-container .left p {
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: var(--fw-light);
  margin: 0px 632px 57px 105px;
  color: white;
}

.bia-container .left a.btn {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 10px 23px;
  border: 1px solid #43D9B8;
  margin: 0 0px 84px 105px;
  color: white;
}

.bia-container  .right {
  padding-right: 105px;
}


/* Background header */

.background {
  position: absolute;
  background: linear-gradient(135deg, #43D9B8 0%, #172443 64.58%, #0F052F 84.9%);
  border-radius: 50px 50px 300px 50px;
  width: 1240px;
  height: 585px;
  top: 112px;
}

.background .right {
  position: absolute;
  top: 132px;
  right: 105px;
  left: 803px;
}


/* Animation */

.desktop-nav {
  animation: fadeDown 1000ms forwards;
  opacity: 0;
}

@keyframes fadeDown {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateY(-20px);
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
}

.bia-container .background .right {
  animation: fadeToLeft 800ms forwards cubic-bezier(0.22, 0.32, 0, 1.54);
  opacity: 0;
  animation-delay: 800ms;
}

@keyframes fadeToLeft {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateX(100px);
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
   <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8" />
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
      <!-- Google Fonts-->
      <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
      <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
      <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@300;400;500;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
      <script src="main.js"></script>
   </head>
   <body>
            <div class="desktop-nav">
            <nav>
              <div class="logo">
                <a href="#">
                    <img src="Images/bia-logo.svg" alt="">
                </a>
              </div>
                <ul class="menu-items">
                    <li>
                        <a href="#" class="active">Home</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Services</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Contact</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#" class="btn">Neem contact op</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
              </nav>
            </div>
         <!-- End of desktop navigation -->
         <div class="wrapper">
            <div class="bia-container">
                <div class="background">
                    <div class="left">
                        <h1>Make data work for you</h1>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In ut neque faucibus gravida viverra tristique. Morbi quis commodo interdum id risus. Vitae hac viverra dui quis lobortis parturient purus. Libero pharetra tortor.</p>
                        <a href="#" class="btn">Neem contact op</a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="right">
                        <img src="Images/header-analytics.svg" alt="">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
     </div>
     <div class="container">
     <div class="test">
        <p> content under neath original content </p>
     </div>
     </div>
     
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: When I try that, I get the following: https://imgur.com/a/2jrH4Zf. The 'Bia-container' gets a height of 0px. Do you happen to know why this happens?

Comment: @SLAC please see the additions I made. I suggest staying away from `position: absolute;` as much as possible if you can. Your default way of positioning should be flex or grid and not absolute. I hope this helps.